# Plasma lines texture

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture

I recently found an [amazing fractal image](http://tatasz.deviantart.com/art/Speed-417113455) that apart from his beauty it fascinated me for the texture present in the petals:
[image]

The problems is that after days trying with the wave filter (and some other techniques) applied to some lines, I realized that is impossible for me to imitate the neon-like effect.

I have made countless searches in Google, without any luck; so this is my last resort.

**Question:** How can I replicate the texture, or where can I find something similar?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, that original fractal image is amazing.

I think you should be able to make something like the portions you’re after, just using Photoshop and a few filters. Here’s a really quick and hacky attempt.

[image]

And here’s how I made it.

#### Make some fibers

[image]

#### Blur 'em

[image]

#### Motion blur 'em

[image]

#### Levels 'em (more contrast)

[image]

#### Add a gradient map

[image]

Because, [gradient maps are the best thing in the world](http://bjango.com/articles/gradientmaps/).

And you're pretty much done. I just did that again on another layer, used a little bit of Filter → Distort → Wave, and painted some soft dots on another bitmap layer under the gradient map.

#### The PSD!

Download: [Plasma lines.psd.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4uurfw1y8ec74le/Plasma%20lines.psd.zip?dl=0)

I hope that helps!

Comment: The image is best fractal flower have seen so far.